# Add custom tiles to ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, tiles, leaflet

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, I made custom tiles for a map I'm using with Leaflet. I have a simple HTML page that can display my custom map with my custom tiles but when I'm trying to use the same code in my ASP site, then I;m not sure how to have the tiles appear. I have created a folder to contain the tiles within the project and tried to reference it with the local file path but when I'm debugging I notice that my site is going through IIS somehow cause it navigates to the page w/ a localhost and port in the address. Is there something I can change in the web.config to have access to my tiles?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger compiles your project and launches it as an application using a lightweight version of IIS. It then opens a browser of your choice to view the website "online". When you publish the project (build>publish) you can move these files to a web server. The reason you see localhost is because the site is being hosted locally (on your machine) and is not public-facing yet.

If you want to reference files in your directory, use a preceding forward slash for for root directory. IE src="/images/tiles/leaflet.png" This will make the code adapt to any domain you might host it on.